# How can I achive this target with css?

Tags: html, css

If you will enter the main page of youtube and try to shrink thw width of it, then the videos amount will shrink also.

So for example, if you have this screen(`width: 500px;`):

```
 _____      _____     _____     _____
|     |    |     |   |     |   |     |
|_____|    |_____|   |_____|   |_____|
```

Then if you shrink the screen ti be with `width: 300px;`, just two videos will appear on the screan, and the other two videos will get the property `visibility` with the value `hidden` (I assume this what happends...).

```
 _____      _____  
|     |    |     |  
|_____|    |_____|
```

How can I exactly get this aim to be done?
I thought about giving any video another id (like "video-1" etcetera...), and with the abbility of using `@media screen...` - just change the `visibility` property of each video each time.

I wanted to know the optimal and shorter way to do that, before im doing my way.
You know... to learn new thought it is a good thing to do :)

Comment: Search about responsive templating.

Comment: The entire technique what you explained can be put in just one word - "**responsive**" in webapps

Comment: You should change the title of the question so it reflects the content. The title is too vague now.

Comment: You can achieve this in many ways. The example you mentioned uses a slider and depending on the view width the slider shows more or less items.

You can follow different approaches, like hiding elements, sliding them, using grid layouts etc... 

I would suggest using plain CSS with some smart Media Queries to implement a simple slider. There are plenty of examples in the web and many tutorials.

Searching for 'Responsive slider carousel' or 'Simple CSS slider carousel' would be a good start. Take a look, give it a try and if you still encounter problems come back, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I think TS has done his best to explain his issue but his knowledge of both the subject or the English language for that matter is not very good. I gave him an answer he could use to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set the 'bleeded div's' (those dropping off the screen) to visibility hidden.

You can achieve this with a div as a mask wherein the smaller div's reside.

Set this mask to the same height as the smaller div's therein. Set the CSS attribute `overflow-y` to `hidden`. All the smaller div's inside need to be floated with `float:left`.

This way you get the effect you are looking for.

Example:

HTML

```
<div class="mask">
  <div class="inner">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mask {height:200px;width:auto;overflow-y:hidden}
.mask .inner {float:left;height:200px;width:200px;margin-right:10px}
```